# SharePoint Rest API to select Url from File Version

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, versioning

I have used the following URL:

```
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/teams/Analytics/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/Analytics/Shared%20Documents/DataMaster')/Files('Transaction.xlsx')/versions
```

which returns a response like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://xyz2.sharepoint.com/teams/Analytics/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>b1ab594c-bf9b-4a8c-b6ca-47d2693d280a</id>
    <title/>
    <updated>2021-11-08T21:41:11Z</updated>
    <entry>
<id>https://xyz2.sharepoint.com/teams/Analytics/_api/SP.FileVersiona7520a03-5e2c-48fd-a242-c18d5db39753</id>
        <category term="SP.FileVersion" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
        <link rel="edit" href="SP.FileVersiona7520a03-5e2c-48fd-a242-c18d5db39753"/>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="SP.FileVersiona7520a03-5e2c-48fd-a242-c18d5db39753/CreatedBy"/>
        <title/>
        <updated>2021-11-08T21:41:11Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name/>
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:CheckInComment/>
                <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2020-10-06T18:32:33Z</d:Created>
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">512</d:ID>
                <d:IsCurrentVersion m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsCurrentVersion>
                <d:Length m:type="Edm.Int64">14291</d:Length>
                <d:Size m:type="Edm.Int32">14291</d:Size>
                <d:Url>_vti_history/512/Shared Documents/DataMaster/Transaction.xlsx</d:Url>
                <d:VersionLabel>1.0</d:VersionLabel>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
<entry>
        <id>https://xyz2.sharepoint.com/teams/Analytics/_api/SP.FileVersion768ebce6-3f23-452c-82a9-2ff52068c4cb</id>
        <category term="SP.FileVersion" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
        <link rel="edit" href="SP.FileVersion768ebce6-3f23-452c-82a9-2ff52068c4cb"/>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="SP.FileVersion768ebce6-3f23-452c-82a9-2ff52068c4cb/CreatedBy"/>
        <title/>
        <updated>2021-11-08T21:41:11Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name/>
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:CheckInComment/>
                <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2021-11-05T14:32:03Z</d:Created>
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">51712</d:ID>
                <d:IsCurrentVersion m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsCurrentVersion>
                <d:Length m:type="Edm.Int64">497893</d:Length>
                <d:Size m:type="Edm.Int32">497893</d:Size>
                <d:Url>_vti_history/51712/Shared Documents/DataMaster/Transaction.xlsx</d:Url>
                <d:VersionLabel>101.0</d:VersionLabel>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>https://xyz2.sharepoint.com/teams/Analytics/_api/SP.FileVersiona29c3e86-f79d-49fa-b8be-0fa838c940c8</id>
        <category term="SP.FileVersion" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
        <link rel="edit" href="SP.FileVersiona29c3e86-f79d-49fa-b8be-0fa838c940c8"/>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="SP.FileVersiona29c3e86-f79d-49fa-b8be-0fa838c940c8/CreatedBy"/>
        <title/>
        <updated>2021-11-08T21:41:11Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name/>
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:CheckInComment/>
                <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2021-11-05T14:37:14Z</d:Created>
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">52224</d:ID>
                <d:IsCurrentVersion m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsCurrentVersion>
                <d:Length m:type="Edm.Int64">497893</d:Length>
                <d:Size m:type="Edm.Int32">497893</d:Size>
                <d:Url>_vti_history/52224/Shared Documents/DataMaster/Transaction.xlsx</d:Url>
                <d:VersionLabel>102.0</d:VersionLabel>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>https://xyz2.sharepoint.com/teams/Analytics/_api/SP.FileVersion696732fc-c075-417f-9d6b-8beda872fcc8</id>
        <category term="SP.FileVersion" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
        <link rel="edit" href="SP.FileVersion696732fc-c075-417f-9d6b-8beda872fcc8"/>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy" href="SP.FileVersion696732fc-c075-417f-9d6b-8beda872fcc8/CreatedBy"/>
        <title/>
        <updated>2021-11-08T21:41:11Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name/>
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:CheckInComment/>
                <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2021-11-05T19:44:26Z</d:Created>
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">52736</d:ID>
                <d:IsCurrentVersion m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsCurrentVersion>
                <d:Length m:type="Edm.Int64">500815</d:Length>
                <d:Size m:type="Edm.Int32">500815</d:Size>
                <d:Url>_vti_history/52736/Shared Documents/DataMaster/Transaction.xlsx</d:Url>
                <d:VersionLabel>103.0</d:VersionLabel>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

However, I want to create REST URL which only returns the following information only and nothing else. I only want the information inside `<d:Url></d:Url>` tag and rest of the information is not required.

Is there any way for me to use a select statement in the REST Url to have only that information returned.

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add `$select` to the endpoint like:

```
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/teams/Analytics/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/Analytics/Shared%20Documents/DataMaster')/Files('Transaction.xlsx')/versions?$select=Url
```

This will return only `Url` property like:

```
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
        <d:Url>_vti_history/512/Shared Documents/DataMaster/Transaction.xlsx</d:Url>
    </m:properties>
</content>
```